# how insert line break in alert message in react-native-awesome-alerts

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-awesome-alerts in my code . 
In alert message i want to break the text into a new line

it should be like the below image

[alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncmcY.png)

please help me how to do it

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import AwesomeAlert from 'react-native-awesome-alerts';

export default class Alert extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showAlert: false };
  }

  showAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true
    });
  };

  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { showAlert } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text>I'm AwesomeAlert</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          this.showAlert();
        }}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Try me!</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <AwesomeAlert
          show={showAlert}
          showProgress={false}
          message='Incorrect Username/Password Used{“\n”}Please try again…'
          messageStyle={styles.textStyle}
          closeOnTouchOutside={true}
          closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.alertStyle}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 7,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#AEDEF4',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 15
  },
  alertStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white', 
    height: 100,
    width: '60%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 7,
    color: 'red'
  },
  textStyle: {
      fontSize: 14,
      color: 'black',
      alignItems: 'center'
  }

});
```

i have tried 'Incorrect Username/Password Used{“\n”}Please try again…' but still no luck

please let me know where it is going wrong

Comment: Hi Rama, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question implies the difficulty is in adding the line break. Can you post your code that creates an alert without the linebreak? Also say what attempts you've made to add the line break.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change your message string to using backtick ` and add \n. This should work now.

```
message={`Incorrect Username/Password Used \n Please try again…`}
```

You might also change the container width to 80% and add `textAlign:"centre"` to textStyle CSS so that that it look better.

Here is what I managed to produce:

[image]

Comment: unfortunanly it doesn't help

Comment: It seems line break doesn't work until the line/string is long enough. For me, it didn't work for `Alert.alert(File Downloaded\n1.jpg")}` but worked for `{Alert.alert("File Downloaded...\n1.jpg")}` and `Alert.alert("File Downloaded\n⨀ 1.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view with width to 80% and add textAlign: "centre" to AwesomeAlert messageStyle so that it looks better.

```
<View style={{ width: '80%' }}>
   <AwesomeAlert
      show={showAlert}
      showProgress={false}
      message='Incorrect Username/Password Used{“\n”}Please try again…'
      messageStyle={styles.textStyle}
      closeOnTouchOutside={true}
      closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.alertStyle}
   />
<View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple AlertTitle tags inside the alert

```
<Alert>
    <AlertTitle>First line's Text Goes Here</AlertTitle>
    <AlertTitle>Second line's Text Goes Here</AlertTitle>
</Alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main solutions for this.

Method 1: Just add the '\n' like below

```
<Text>
   First Line {'\n'} Second Line.
</Text>
```

Method 2: Add the line break it in the string literals, like below.

```
 <Text>
   `First Line  
   Second Line`.
 </Text>
```

For more information, please refer the below tutorial.

https://cutt.ly/ZZ50BCR